# Оплата в зависимости от города

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, api

Как можно узнать способы оплаты для клиентов, в определенном городе,как [здесь](https://gepur.com/help?way=payment)

Comment: Метод оплаты не зависит от города.

Comment: ТС, город для сайта нужен только (чаще всего) для адресации. Учитывается страна, ибо где-то есть какой-то банк, где-то нет. Посылаете AJAX запрос в таблицу со способами оплаты, передавая идентификатор страны, в ответ получаете список платежек и выводите его.

Comment: то есть это вручную все заносится? мне создать таблицу и туда писать из админки?